# Is US scientific output decreasing (as of 2022)? If not, why not?

Tags: publications, united-states

Inspired by [this article](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-022-03604-9) in *Nature*.

> After a steady increase, numbers peaked in 2016, when more than one million students — undergraduate and graduate — were enrolled to study in the United States. The number of international students then began to decline slowly: graduate-student numbers dipped by 1.3%, to 377,943, in 2018, according to the Institute of International Education, a student-exchange non-profit organization based in New York City. During the 2020–21 academic year, the first of the COVID-19 pandemic, the number sank by 12.1%, to 329,272 graduate students. That same year, numbers of international scholars in the United States (specifically, postdocs and visiting researchers) plummeted by 31%, from 123,508 to 85,528.

These double-digit decreases seem large enough that intuitively one would expect scientific output to decrease too. Is that happening?

[Scimago's journal and country ranking](https://www.scimagojr.com/countryrank.php?order=itp&ord=desc&year=2017) gives these numbers for US "documents" from 2017 to 2021:

- 2017: 709480
- 2018: 718762
- 2019: 707258
- 2020: 700795
- 2021: 726552

So it doesn't look like it's decreasing. In that case, the next question is: why not?

Comment: Papers are a lagging indicator for one.

Comment: If one clicks on "United States" in the link, one gets a subject specific list which shows several phenomena that one can't see at the aggregated level: between 2019 and 2021, there is a sharp decline in publications in engineering and computer science (maybe due to the role of conference publications in these fields?), and a sharp increase in medicine. Between 2020 and 2021, medicine alone accounts for an increase of about 20 000 publications. There are similar effects for related fields such as biochemistry, etc. So one might guess that CoV19-publications cause a strong bias in the numbers.

Comment: (Probably this does not explain the entire effect, but it seems to have a strong impact on the numbers that one should keep in mind.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck - indeed, I suspect Covid had broad impacts on all productivity (except Covid-related medical research). Can't work in a lab, can't have coffee chats easily, etc. It may take 5 years or more to recover all the social connections that lubricate research activities.